# Find a specified word frequency through time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with three columns.

```
Date Account Text
12    F.G.   There is a dog outside 
34    R.A.   Where are my keys?
34    F.H.   Have you ever seen titanic? 
34    V.B.   I found this dog.
34    K.J.   You have a lovely dog 
36    F.E.   How old is your sister?
```

I would like to search for a word, e.g. dog, through the columns reporting the count by day to see if there is a day where it was more frequent.

I know how to extract a word from a data frame’s column, but I do not know how to determine the count by date.

I think that I could first filter rows from data frame where the word dog appears, then group by date.

Do you think it makes sense? Would it be correct to proceed  in such way?

My output would be:

```
 Date   Count
    12    1 
    34    2 
    36    0
```

...

Comment: I am having difficulties to save the formatting code at the bottom. Could you please try to edit it? Thank you so much and sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do `set_index` with `str` `count` then sum the same date with `sum` pass `level`

```
s=df.set_index('Date').Text.str.count('dog').sum(level=0).\
        to_frame('count').reset_index()
s
   Date  count
0    12      1
1    34      2
2    36      0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start by creating an extra column with the `count` and then sum the values per `Date` with a `groupby`

```
df['dog_count'] = df['Text'].str.count('dog')
Output_df = df.groupby('Date')['dog_count'].sum()
```

Sorry for formatting, posting from phone